# Is it possible to calculate the standard error of beta0 and beta1 with only their Estimates and Confidence Intervals in R?

Tags: r

How do you calculate the standard error of beta0 and beta1 using only their Estimates and Confidence Intervals and the qt function in R?

Example:

```
       Est   SE    L    U
beta0 1.13 0.241 0.889 1.37
beta1 3.57 1.620 1.950 5.19
```

Comment: In your example it looks like your L/U values are just Est +/ SE. So you wan just take Est-L without worrying about the distribution (just simple subtraction). Otherwise do you know how many degrees of freedom the `t` distribution has? This seems more like a question about statistics than programming and might be a better fit for [stat.se].

Comment: Yes, I've taken df as 2